# Pandas Float decimals

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I`m trying to write to a csv a pandas DataFrame with a column with various data types. I need all the float values to have exactly 4 decimal places.

For example. I define a new df:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0.24567899874, 'a'], 'col2' : [0.123456789, 1] })
```

And then writting it to a csv file using float_format:

```
df.to_csv('example.csv', float_format='%.4f')
```

I get the result:
col1, col2 
0.24999999999986597,0.1234
a,1.0000

It seems that float_format only applies to columns in which all their elements are numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: '{:.4f}'.format(x) if type(x) is int or type(x) is float else x)

df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == 'float':
        df[col].round(4)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.